# Мерцание элемента в SVG-картинке

Tags: css, html5, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Внутри SVG-файла есть элемент, например `<g id="blink">...</g>`, внутри него ещё много всего.
 Как сделать, чтобы `opacity` у всего содержимого внутри `blink` постоянно циклично менялось, например с 0.5 на 1, и опять на 0.5?

Comment: можно так же как и не для svg - при помощи css анимации

Comment: @Alexashka вас минусуют потому что, у вас не было попытки попытаться как-то самостоятельно порешать свой вопрос. Если хотите получать быстрые ответы и не получать минусы добавляйте всегда код вашей попытки в вопрос  [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4):

### SVG анимация

Если нужно анимировать все элементы, которые находятся внутри группы, то можно добавить команду анимации перед закрывающим групповым тегом `</g>`

```
 <animate
  attributeName="opacity"
  dur="1s"
  values="0.5;1;0.5"
  repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="240" height="220" viewBox="0 0 240 220" >

<rect x="10" y="10" width="240" height="280" rx="10" fill="#151515" />
 <!-- Блок для анимации opacity  -->
 <g id="blink" opacity="1"> 
  <rect x="20" y="20" width="50" height="25" rx="10" fill="skyblue" />
    <rect x="100" y="20" width="50" height="25" rx="10" fill="yellow" /> 
   <rect x="180" y="20" width="50" height="25" rx="10" fill="greenyellow" /> 
 <animate
  attributeName="opacity"
  dur="1s"
  values="0.5;1;0.5"
  repeatCount="indefinite" />
</g>  
   <!-- Вторая группа элементов, которая статична -->
   <g>
   <circle cx="35" cy="120" r="15" fill="purple" /> 
    <circle cx="115" cy="120" r="15" fill="yellow" />  
    <circle cx="195" cy="120" r="15" fill="dodgerblue" />  
 </g>   
</svg>
```

### CSS анимация

Обратите внимание на то, что одна и та же css анимация `animation: fade 800ms infinite;` применена к разным группам с разными условиями. Элементы первой группа мерцают постоянно. Элементы второй группы мерцают при наведении.

```css
#blink {
 animation: fade 800ms infinite;
}
 @keyframes fade {
     0% { fill-opacity: 0.5; }
    12% { fill-opacity: 1; }
    100% { fill-opacity: 0.5; }
   } 
   
   #circleBlink:hover { 
   animation: fade 0.5s infinite;
   
   }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="240" height="220" viewBox="0 0 240 220" >

<rect x="10" y="10" width="240" height="280" rx="10" fill="#151515" />
 <!-- Блок для анимации opacity  -->
 <g id="blink" > 
  <rect x="20" y="20" width="50" height="25" rx="10" fill="skyblue" />
    <rect x="100" y="20" width="50" height="25" rx="10" fill="yellow" /> 
   <rect x="180" y="20" width="50" height="25" rx="10" fill="greenyellow" /> 
 
</g>  
   <!-- Вторая группа элементов начинает мерцать при наведении -->
   
 <rect class="rect" x="15" y="95" width="220" height="70" rx="5"  fill="#bababa" /> 
 <g id="circleBlink">
   <circle cx="35" cy="120" r="15" fill="purple" /> 
    <circle cx="115" cy="120" r="15" fill="green" />  
    <circle cx="195" cy="120" r="15" fill="dodgerblue" />  
    <text x="135" y="155" font-size="18" text-anchor="middle"> Hover me </text>
 </g>   
</svg>
```